# Record<string, unknown> is missing the properties of CustomType

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this setup in my project:

```js
interface GenericFn<TInput extends Record<string, unknown>, TOutput extends Record<string, unknown>> {
    (input: TInput): TOutput;
}

type AddNumberInput = {
    number1: number;
    number2: number;
};

type AddNumberOutput = {
    sum: number;
};
```

And whenever I try to do this:

```js
const fn1: GenericFn<AddNumberInput, AddNumberOutput> = (input) => { 
    return { sum: input.number1 + input.number2 }; 
};

const fn2: GenericFn<Record<string, unknown>, Record<string, unknown>> = fn1; // ERROR 2322
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'GenericFn<AddNumberInput, AddNumberOutput>' is not assignable to type 'GenericFn<Record<string, unknown>, Record<string, unknown>[]>'.

  Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'AddNumberInput': number1, number2 ts(2322)
```

However, I have confirmed that `AddNumberInput` and `AddNumberOutput` can be assigned to type `Record<string, unknown>`:

```js
const type1: AddNumberInput = {
    number1: 1,
    number2: 2
};
const type2: AddNumberOutput = {
    sum: 3
};

let genericType: Record<string, unknown>;
genericType = type1; // No errors
genericType = type2; // No errors
```

How should this be done instead? I would like to store each generic function in an object collection, like so:

```js
const fns: {
    [id: string]: GenericFn<Record<string, unknown>, Record<string, unknown>>
} = {};

fns["fn1"] = fn1; // ERROR 2322
```

but I cannot seem to store them because of this error. How should this be implemented instead? Thanks!

Edit: As requested, here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, this is the `tsconfig.json` that comes with the Create-React-App Typescript template.

Comment: Hey  running `tsc` on the above code doesn't give any error for me. Could you kindly provide your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @h-sifat I have updated the question to include my `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: you don't need to define return type upfront. See this example: `https://tsplay.dev/mLRpZw`

Comment: I tried looking around a lot, can't really find anything solid. If you want something quick and simple, do this: `fns["fn1"] = fn1 as any;`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this can be fixed by setting the `strictFunctionTypes` setting to `false` in `tsconfig.json`. However, I am not sure what the consequences of having this setting off will be during the development of my application. Perhaps I'll have to look for an alternative that may fit my needs better.

Comment: IF type safety is important for you, don't do this.

Comment: I definitely agree, that's why I'm hesitant to make this the final answer to this problem. It still is a possible solution, but I'm also looking for other solutions for this.